# XUbuntu - change default Terminal windows size/layout

Tags: xubuntu

Can someone help how to change default Terminal windows size in XUbuntu?

After some surfing, I found instructions for Gnome. Maybe I don't understand, but XUbuntu doesn't use Gnome?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18):

You can configure your terminal behavior

- 13.10 and below: ~/.config/Terminal/terminalrc
- 14.04 and onwards: ~/.config/xfce4/terminal/terminalrc

Use the `MiscDefaultGeometry` option

```
[Configuration]
MiscDefaultGeometry=132x24
```

To perform a "visual" adaptation, resize the terminal window to the desired size then use `stty size` to determine the current window size.

For additional information see

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man1/xfce4-terminal.1.html
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man7/X.7.html

On that last page, on X, scroll down to the geometry section.

Comment: You can also set default position:  `MiscDefaultGeometry=132x24+250+30` positions the window 250 pixels from the left and 30 from the top of the screen.

Comment: The file has moved to: .config/xfce4/terminal/terminalrc