# Set Terminal window size (and position)

Tags: command-line, lubuntu

I use Lubuntu and want to set bigger Terminal window (for default).
How can I do that?

Maybe in lxterminal.conf but how?

Comment: Greetings - this previously answered question is probably what you are looking for: **http://askubuntu.com/questions/86066/xubuntu-change-default-terminal-windows-size-layout**

Comment: @kingmilo: The OP is using Lubuntu which uses `lxterminal` whereas the question refers to Xubuntu which uses `xfce4-terminal`

Answer (score 5):

This can be done in two different ways, depending on whether access is from the keyboard or via the menu.

**From the keyboard**:

One has to edit `~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml`.

> note: it's always a good thing to save a copy of `lubuntu-rc.xml`
>   first (*lubuntu-rc.xml.old*)

Use a text editor to open `~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml`.  This file has several sections; in the section devoted to keybindings, add this:

```
<keybind key="C-A-T">
<action name="Execute"> 
<command>lxterminal --geometry=140x40</command> 
</action>
</keybind>
```

Save the file and exit the text editor. Open a terminal and run `openbox --reconfigure` to refresh lubuntu-rc.xml. After this, any time you access lxterminal from the keyboard using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, lxterminal will open with a size of 140 columns by 40 rows.

**From the menu**:
This requires editing of a `.desktop` file. By default, .desktop files are located in `/usr/share/applications` and could be edited there (using `sudo`).
However, it may be preferable to make a copy of the .desktop file in `~/.local/share/applications` because editing *this* file only affects the specific user (and doesn't need `sudo`).

So, copy `/usr/share/applications/lxterminal.desktop` to `~/.local/share/applications`. Then open the copied file with a text editor. Search for a line that starts with `Exec=` and change `Exec=lxterminal` to `Exec=lxterminal --geometry=140x40`. Save the file. Done.

Comment: it's not want you wanted or it doesn't work at all?

Comment: Both the answers on this page helped me but I cannot figure out how to change the starting position of the window. Currently, it opens on the right but I'd like the window to open left and top aligned.

Answer (score 5):

I succeeded in increasing the window size for lxterminal by editing

```
/usr/share/applications/lxterminal.desktop
```

changing the `Exec` line to

```
Exec=lxterminal --geometry=81x59
```